# Registering components with metadata in Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I am registering multiple components for a service and I want to provide additional metadata to the components that I can get without resolving the service.

With Microsoft extensibility framework you can provide your exports with additional metadata as seen here [MEF Metadata and Metadata Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/attributed-programming-model-overview-mef#metadata-and-metadata-views), is there something similar in Windsor?

I am currently trying to wrap my component in a class with 2 properties, IMetadata and Lazy  where the lazy would resolve the component when needed.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();

        // register the wrapped object that contains the Component metadata and a lazy to resolve the component
        container.Register(
            Classes.FromThisAssembly()
            .BasedOn<IService>()
            .Configure(config =>
            {
                // create wrapper
                var wrapper = new WrappedComponent();
                wrapper.ComponentImpl = new Lazy<IService>(() => container.Resolve<IService>(config.Name));

                // add metadata to the wrapper 
                if (config.Implementation.IsDefined(typeof(ComponentMetadataAttribute), false))
                {
                    var metadata = (IComponentMetadata)config.Implementation.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ComponentMetadataAttribute), false)[0];
                    wrapper.Metadata = metadata;
                }

                // set the component to the wrapper
                config.Instance(wrapper);
            })
            // also set service to wrapper
            .WithService.Select((impl, services) => new List<Type>() { typeof(WrappedComponent) }));

        // register the components
        container.Register(
            Classes.FromThisAssembly()
            .BasedOn<IService>().Configure(config =>
            {
                if (config.Implementation.IsDefined(typeof(ComponentMetadataAttribute), false))
                {
                    var metadata = (IComponentMetadata)config.Implementation.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ComponentMetadataAttribute), false)[0];

                    config.Named(metadata.Name);
                }
            }));
    }
}

public class WrappedComponent
{
    public IComponentMetadata Metadata { get; set; }
    public Lazy<IService> ComponentImpl { get; set; }
}
[ComponentMetadata]
public class MyComponent : IService
{
    public void Operation()
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}


public interface IService
{
    void Operation();
}

public class ComponentMetadataAttribute : Attribute, IComponentMetadata
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherMetadata { get; set; }
}

public interface IComponentMetadata
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
    string SomeOtherMetadata { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `WrappedComponent` more generic and simplify your registrations by handling off the extraction of the metadata and lazy loaded component to the `WrappedComponent` class.

`WrappedComponent` takes the `IKernel` (from Castle Windsor) and uses it to determine the implementing type of the `TComponent` service from which metadata is retrieved. It also uses the `IKernel` to initialise the `Lazy` object. Remembering to handle the release of the `TComponent` as we're explicitly resolving it.

```
public class WrappedComponent<TComponent> : IDisposable
{
    private readonly IKernel kernel;

    public WrappedComponent(IKernel kernel)
    {
        this.kernel = kernel;

        var componentType = this.kernel.GetHandler(typeof(TComponent)).ComponentModel.Implementation;

        this.Metadata = componentType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ComponentMetadataAttribute), false)
                            .Cast<ComponentMetadataAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();

        this.ComponentImpl = new Lazy<TComponent>(() => this.kernel.Resolve<TComponent>());
    }

    public IComponentMetadata Metadata { get; }

    public Lazy<TComponent> ComponentImpl { get; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (this.ComponentImpl.IsValueCreated)
        {
            this.kernel.ReleaseComponent(this.ComponentImpl.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Registration becomes as simple as...

```
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(WrappedComponent<>)).LifestyleTransient());
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IService>().WithService.FromInterface().LifestyleTransient());
```

I've assumed a `Transient` lifestyle, but whichever lifestyle you use, it'll be best to use the same for the `WrappedComponent` and `IService`.

`IService`, `MyComponent`, `ComponentMetadataAttribute` and `IComponentMetadata` remain unchanged.